# Problem evaluating the equation 2 ^  −√3 +sin x/2

Tags: c

I have to write a program that will evaluate the equation `2 ^ − √3+ x/2`, where `1 <= x <= 180` [No checking needed].
[Here there are problem's Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2Vru.png)

Those are some sample output:

Input:
`30`
Output:
`1.810066`

Input
`120`
Output
`0.778151`

Input
`180`
Output
`3.954243`

This is what I've tried so far, but it does not match the output wanted

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double x;
    double result;
    scanf("%lf", &x);

    result = 2 * pow(cos(x),2) - sqrt(3) * sin(x) + sin(x / 2);

    printf("%.8lf\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the sample inputs, what *is* the actual output?

Comment: As a proable hint about the problem: The [`sin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sin) and [`cos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/cos) function expects their inputs to be angles in *radians*, not degrees.

Comment: It's like any calculator. The first thing you do when picking one up is to scratch your head to figure out if it uses radians or degrees, before you use any trig functions. Except C has no option to conveniently switch, so you have to calculate degrees manually.